# Google recommendations AI deleting catalog items error 403

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-recommendation

I am trying to integrate my catalog into google recommendations ai, and for debugging purposes I want to be able to delete items from the catalog once imported. The documentations suggests running the following code:

```
curl -X DELETE \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
"https://retail.googleapis.com/v2/projects/[PROJECT_NUMBER]/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/[PRODUCT_ID]"
```

which returns the following error:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the retail.googleapis.com. We recommend configuring the billing/quota_project setting in gcloud or using a service account through the auth/impersonate_service_account setting. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "retail.googleapis.com",
          "consumer": "[redacted for privacy]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Running the suggested code with the --impersonate-service-account flag, results in the same error as above, but preceded with

> WARNING: Impersonate service account '[name redacted for privacy]' is detected. This command cannot be used to print the access token for an impersonate account. The token below is still the application default credentials' access token.

If I attempt to log in for authorization instead of printing an access token, I get the following error:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

The link provided is no longer working. I would like to know how to provide proper authorization/authentication for deleting an item from the recommendation ai catalog.

PS. The account I am using to do this is the owner of the project, and as such should have all the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

To set up authentication for your application of local cURL request to Recommendations AI. You have to [create a  Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/retail/recommendations-ai/docs/setting-up#service-account), download SA key, and set the environment variable 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' to the key so allow your local cURL request noted in the original description

If you are unable to download a SA key file, I kindly suggest to try to use a ! before the curl like this, !curl -X POST , also if you are familiar with Python, it's recommended to use the [python library](https://googleapis.dev/python/recommendationengine/latest/index.html)  for Recommendations AI.